# How to send a serialized JSON for this JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, http

I am sending a Serialized JSON via http call like this:

```
        var bodyObj = new
        {
            memo = "Test Memo",
            claims = new[] {
                             new { id = "1030003001131009259" , value = "30"},
                             new { id = "1030003001131009259" , value = "30"}
                         }
        };
var Obj = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, Obj))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //codes
                }
            }
```

But, I am getting 422 http error.
The requested API accepts JSON as body like this:

```
{
  
    "memo": "Test Memo",
    "claims": [
        {
            "id": "1026805104377857150",
            "value": "10"
        },
        {
            "id": "1025621933162497665",
            "value": "10"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: pls post the whole code, one line is certainly not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bug, since you have already serialized data, you can not use PostAsJsonAsync, use

```
using var response = await client.PostAsync(url, Obj)
```